# JQuery Ajax Plugin File Upload simplify code

Tags: jquery, file, jquery-plugins, upload

I am currently using Valums JQuery File Upload plugin. The plugin is very convenient to use, but I do not like how the code looks. Because it occupied inside `document.ready` such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#button1'), interval;

    new AjaxUpload(button, {
        action: 'http://test.com/user/uploadfile', 
        name: 'myfile',
        onSubmit : function(file, ext){
            // change button text, when user selects file           
            button.text('Uploading');

            // If you want to allow uploading only 1 file at time,
            // you can disable upload button
            this.disable();

            // Uploding -> Uploading. -> Uploading...
            interval = window.setInterval(function(){
                var text = button.text();
                if (text.length < 13){
                    button.text(text + '.');                    
                } else {
                    button.text('Uploading');               
                }
            }, 200);
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            button.text('Upload Finished');

            window.clearInterval(interval);

            // enable upload button
            //this.enable();

            alert(response);            
        }
    });
});
```

My question is can the code be more simplified? So that I can have the code more or less look like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#button1'), interval;

    new AjaxUpload(button, {#leads to another function}#);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you new to Javascript? I remember my first experiences with Javascript & jQuery were interesting because I didn't like the way my code looked at first. The thing is that you really have to get used to it and understand that it is all there for a reason. Writing a custom plugin to  do things like this would work, but in the end, you'll still have that code stashed away somewhere. Just pick a code nesting scheme you like and be proud of what you have working because 99% of your guests prolly won't really care =)